# Meleze.web asp.net mvc 3 razor minify and compress html

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, minify

I have find meleze.web in nuget to remove extra white spaces in generated html result.
but when i set web.config new  , and run  nothing happend to result.
is there any correct sample or special configs ?

```
<configuration>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="Meleze.Web.Razor.MinifyHtmlWebRazorHostFactory,Meleze.Web.Razor" />
 </system.web.webPages.razor>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a little bit of context, we're talking about the tool described here: http://cestdumeleze.net/blog/2011/minifying-the-html-with-asp-net-mvc-and-razor/

I used the following config:

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <system.web.webPages.razor>
        <host factoryType="Meleze.Web.Razor.MinifyHtmlWebRazorHostFactory, Meleze.Web, Version=1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a868b5321967eda" />
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have changed the /web.config instead of the /Views/web.config that config.

Contact the package owner if needed to get help ;-)