# using Meleze.web with razor generator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, minify

I use RazorGenerator for my mvc views, now i try to optimize my views html with meleze.web but it just no work.
I have review the configuration several times and everything is fine in /Views/Web.config

```
<configuration>
   <system.web.webPages.razor>     
    <host factoryType="Meleze.Web.Razor.MinifyHtmlWebRazorHostFactory, Meleze.Web, Version=1.0.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a868b5321967eda" />

 </system.web.webPages.razor>
 </configuration>
```

I receive no error, no exception, nothing at all
Its looks like Meleze.web is never been invoked.

Any idea? i have google a lot without any result.

Comment: Sometimes you need to clean the solution and build it again.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you check [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062781/meleze-web-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-minify-and-compress-html)

It's the most likely answer to your problems. Further, ensure that you have commented out the existing Razor view engine.

i.e. comment this out

```
<!--<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />-->
```